# How to use comprehension to find dict key when value is "None"?

Tags: python, dictionary

How to use comprehension to find dict key when value is `None`? Is there a one liner instead of the following code?

```
def Func():
    for k, v in some_dict.items()
        if not v:
            return k
```

Comment: `[k for k, v in some_dict.items() if not v]`

Comment: so i need to [k for k, v in some_dict.items() if not v][0]? to get k? what if  all key in some_dict have value? then [k for k.......not v][0] will fail?

Comment: It's a list of all the keys with `None` as value. There could be zero of those in `some_dict`, then the list is empty. There could be more than one.

Comment: Why would you want to use a list-comprehension here? You aren't creating a list!

Comment: I wrote my comment with the intention that you wanted Func() to return every key, not just the first. If that isn't the case, I would recommend looking at the answer posted.

Comment: Side-note: If you actually want `None`, not just "any falsy value", change the test from `not v` to `v is None`; `not v` will match `0`, `0.0`, `False`, `''`, `[]`, `()`, `{}`, etc., not just `None`, while `v is None` will match `None` and only `None`.

Answer (score 5):

```
result = next((k for k, v in some_dict.items() if not v), None)
```

This uses [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to iterate over the generator and return the first `k` whose `v` is falsey, or `None` if no item matches that condition. If you prefer to raise an exception when no item matches, leave out the `None` default value.

Comment: `some_dict.items()` -> `some_dict.iteritems()` for Python 2.x

Comment: Note that if you want the `StopIteration` exception instead of a silent `None` return on failure, you can remove both `, None` and the genexpr parens (because the function call parens can serve double duty) simplifying it to `next(k for k, v in some_dict.items() if not v)`.

Comment: @khachik it's sort of  convention on the [python] tag to assume Python 3 (seeing as Python 2 is almost at the end of its life)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note empty lists will be None, and big lists default gets first element):

```
l=next((k for k, v in some_dict.items() if not v),None)
print(l)
```

Or:

```
l=next((k for k in some_dict.keys() if not some_dict[k]),None)
print(l)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182391/discussion-on-answer-by-u9-forward-how-to-use-comprehension-to-find-dict-key-whe).